# Comparing Every Odd Number with Every Even Number

Tags: java

I am separating the Odd Numbers and Even Numbers from an Arrays. 
My Code is:

```
public class EvenAndOdd {

public static void main (String[] args)
{

    int countEven = 0; 
    int countOdd = 0; 
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; 

    for(int i : myArray) { 
    if(i%2 == 0) { 
      countEven++; 
      System.out.println("EVEN numbers: " + i); 
    } 
    else { 
      countOdd++; 
      System.out.println("ODD numbers: " + i); 
    } 
    } 
    System.out.println("Total Even Number: " + countEven); 
    System.out.println("Total Odd Number " + countOdd); 
      }
}
```

Getting correct result from above Code. But i want to now compare every Odd Number with Every Even Number, if any of Even number is greater than odd Number then return o and no odd Number is greater than Even number return 1.

Comment: OK? What have you tried?

Comment: Not got exact approach , that's why put my query @user3580294

Comment: So what have you got so far?

Comment: Try ur self @user3580294 and then let me know.

Comment: @user3580294 Hasn't even tried the nice {} button on the toolbar to indent code properly so it renders as code.

Comment: How much will you pay me? I don't do other people's work for them for free. I'm not so stingy about helping other people with what they have, though, if they show that they've made an effort ;)

Comment: I will not pay any a single rupee, i am student not a professional. i m doing my own practice @user3580294

Comment: You missed my point (see my last sentence)... The point is, you really should make/show your effort before posting here. SO should be treated as a last resort to a question you have spent every ounce of brainpower on and are still stuck on. If you have done any thinking about this question at all, you have not shown it in your question, hence the rather sarcastic response. I'd say you got lucky with someone willing to do your work for you, but if you're a student, you know just as well as anyone else that that is not how you improve.

Answer (score 0):

code is as below

```
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i+=2)
{
  j=i+1; //odd number

//if even number is greater
  if(myArray[i]>=myArray[j])
   System.out.println(1);
  else //if odd is greater
  System.out.println(0);
}
```

Comment: what is J defined here?

Comment: sorry, write int j instead of j

Comment: whats your expected output, please clarify in well defined format.

Comment: myArray={11, 4, 9, 2, 8}; in this myarray there are two odd number 11 and 9 both are greater than every even number i.e 4,2,8. i want this comparssion if even number greater than odd number then return 0 otherwise return 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand "if any even number is greater than an odd number return 0" and "if no  odd number greater than even return 1" because there is a 7 which is greater than, say 2, but there is a 4 which is greater than 3, or 1. So this means both cases match so there is a flaw in your logic, or poor phrasing of the question. In any case, you might find this useful

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class EvenAndOdd{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int countEven = 0; 
        int countOdd = 0; 
        int result = 0;
        int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i : myArray){
            if(i%2 == 0) { 
                countEven++; 
                System.out.println("EVEN numbers: " + i); 
                evens.add(i);
            } 
            else { 
                countOdd++; 
                System.out.println("ODD numbers: " + i);
                odds.add(i);
            } 
        }

        for(int i : evens){
            for(int j : odds){
                if(i > j)
                    result = 1;
                else
                    result = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + result );
    }

}
```